# Random crash for MFC dialog member variable not in scope

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, scope

I have a MFC application with property window. I property window I have implemented a custom CMFCPropertyGridProperty, So that whenever user click the button added in that property, another dialog pops up.

```
void CMFCPropertyGridCustomProperty::OnClickButton(CPoint point) {
    CSampleDlg* configDlg = new CSampleDlg(NULL);                            
    INT_PTR bResult = configDlg->DoModal();
    if(bResult != 1)        //If user cancels bResult is 2 ,if select ok bResult is 1
    {
        return;
    }
    CString selectedOutput   = configDlg->GetSelectionOutput();
    CString configValue = configDlg->GetSelectionElemValue();
```

but the problem is , When I am running in debug mode, sometimes it is working fine but some times it crashes on configDlg->GetSelectionOutput() line. In callStack, I found that the variable is out of scope at that time.

Here is part of my dialog code:

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CSomeClassDlg, CDialogEx)

    CSomeClassDlg::CSomeClassDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
        : CDialogEx(CSomeClassDlg::IDD, pParent)
    {
        m_DevNameStr    = "";
        m_ElemValue     = "";
    }

    CSomeClassDlg::~CSomeClassDlg()
    {

        delete m_DataXMLTree;
        m_DataXMLTree = NULL;

        delete m_TemplateXMLTree;
        m_TemplateXMLTree = NULL;

    }

    void CSomeClassDlg::OnItemchangedElementList(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
    {
        LPNMLISTVIEW pNMLV = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLISTVIEW>(pNMHDR);
        int nPos = -1;



        nPos = m_ElementListCtrl.GetNextItem(-1,LVNI_SELECTED);
        if(nPos != -1)
        {
            elemDataNode = (CTreeNode*)(m_ElementListCtrl.GetItemData(nSelectedItemIndex));
            elemTepmplateNode = GetTemplateElement(elemDataNode);
            ShowElemDescription(elemDataNode,elemTepmplateNode);
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

        *pResult = 0;
    }


    void CSomeClassDlg::ShowElemDescription(CTreeNode* dataElemNode, CTreeNode* templateElemNode)
    {
        if(dataElemNode==NULL || templateElemNode==NULL)
        {
            m_DescEditCtrl.SetWindowTextA("");
            return;
        }

        CString PIXITStr        = templateElemNode->GetAttributeValue("AssociatedPixit");
        CString descriptionStr  = templateElemNode->GetAttributeValue("Description");
        CString valueStr        = dataElemNode->GetAttributeValue("Value");
        m_DescEditCtrl.SetWindowTextA(descriptionStr);
        m_DevNameStr    = PIXITStr;
        m_ElemValue     = valueStr;

    }

    CString CSomeClassDlg::GetSelectionOutput()
    {
        return m_DevNameStr;
    }
    CString CSomeClassDlg::GetSelectionElemValue()
    {
        return m_ElemValue;
    }
```

But I don't understand if that is the problem then why it is not happening each time. And if it is really the problem what is the best wat to get multiple member variable after doing doModal() . Please help.

Comment: There should be no problem doing that, so the problem lies in the code for your dialog. "Random" problems often indicate uninitialized variables.

Comment: @molbdnilo, in constructor I have initialized it "". Still can not solve it. Actually the variable stores which field is selected in a listctrl and generates a string and store it as meber variable. I have even put breakpoints in OnClickOK function. The value is still accesible there. But after the do modal finishes, this random crash occurs. Can I some how try-catch this to avoid crash atleast ?

Comment: Even if you could catch that kind of exception, and you can't, there's little point in working around a bug by ignoring it. You need to show the dialog code.

Comment: @molbdnilo, added code of the dialog. Please take a look

Comment: Is there any possibility that as I am using parent window of the dialog as NULL is the reason of all this. Should I give a parent CWnd*

Comment: NULL should be safe. Does `configDlg` have the same value before and after `DoModal`? You haven't got a `delete this` lying around somewhere in there?

Comment: @molbdnilo,
CString selectedOutput   = configDlg->GetSelectionOutput();
    CString configValue = configDlg->GetSelectionElemValue();

 after these line I have put a delete configDlg;

strange is that, sometimes it is getting the GetSelectionOutput() properly but crashing while executing next GetSelectionElemValue() call !! :/

Comment: What you describe could be a memory overwrite.  Without seeing all of your code, it's only a guess.  Have you tried using [Application Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20028) to troubleshoot the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have made some changes which had solved this issue.
1.changes the constructor of custom CMFCPropertyGridProperty class , parameter specially of type COleVariant.
2.Changed the dialog class constructor to take a CTreeNode* and store it as member variable. Somehow that pointer was getting corrupted after DoModal.
3.Added some Assert() to check the validity and a Redraw() in onclickbutton() of custom CMFCPropertyGridProperty class.
I do not know the exact reason for all these changes. Found a reference code in [Google code](http://muse-game-engine.googlecode.com/svn/muse/tools/ModelEditor/CustomProperties.cpp)

Here is the OnClickButton of the custom CMFCPropertyGridProperty class:

```
    void CMFCPropertyGridPropertyCustomClass::OnClickButton(CPoint point)
    {   
        ASSERT_VALID(this);
        ASSERT_VALID(m_pWndList);
        ASSERT_VALID(m_pWndInPlace);
        ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_pWndInPlace->GetSafeHwnd()));

        m_bButtonIsDown = TRUE;
        Redraw();

        BOOL bUpdate        = FALSE;
        CString selOutput   = "";

        CSomeClassDlg* configDlg = new CSomeClassDlg(m_selNode);                            
        INT_PTR bResult = configDlg->DoModal();                            
        if(bResult == IDOK)
        {
            bUpdate     = TRUE;
            //Do Something
        }

        if (bUpdate)
        {
            if (m_pWndInPlace != NULL)
            {
                m_pWndInPlace->SetWindowText(selOutput);
            }

            m_varValue = (LPCTSTR) selOutput;
        }

        m_bButtonIsDown = FALSE;
        Redraw();

        if (m_pWndInPlace != NULL)
        {
            m_pWndInPlace->SetFocus();
        }
        else
        {
            m_pWndList->SetFocus();
        }

    }
```

Here is the constructor of the custom CMFCPropertyGridProperty class:

```
     CMFCPropertyGridPropertyCustomClass::CMFCPropertyGridPropertyCustomClass(CTreeNode* pNode, const CString& strName, const CString& varValue, const CString& description) : CMFCPropertyGridProperty(strName, COleVariant((LPCTSTR)varValue), description)
    {
        //some initialization

    }
```